# Keeping UIView pinned to top of screen while resizing height and animating?

Tags: ios, swift, resize, nslayoutconstraint, auto

I have an app with a tab bar controller and two view controllers.  One of those view controllers contains a map which is initially constrained to the safe area layout guide at the top and the bottom of the screen.  When I tap on a button (which you can see in the upper left-hand corner of the screenshot below), I want to shrink (and animate) the height of the map so I can add a new view below it.

Here's the code I am currently using:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    private var mapView = MGLMapView()
    private var button = UIButton()
    private var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!    
    private var mapCollapsed: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])

        let mapViewTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        mapViewTopConstraint.isActive = true

        heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        heightConstraint.isActive = true

        setupButton()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mapView.styleURL = URL(string: "STYLE_URL_HERE")!
        view.addSubview(mapView)
    }

    @objc func updateConstraintsButtonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
        if mapCollapsed == false {
            mapCollapsed = true
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                self.heightConstraint.constant = -150
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        } else {
            mapCollapsed = false
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                self.heightConstraint.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
}
```

For the most part, this appears to be working as I expected but as you can see in the animated GIF below, when I tap the button and call `updateConstraintsButtonTapped(sender:)`, the map view does re-size but while doing do, the entire map view slides down (quickly) from the top of the screen before sliding back up and resizing.  I'd like the top of the map to stay pinned to the safe area layout guide and only see the bottom of the map view move when the resize occurs.  I'm obviously doing something incorrectly.  I tried setting the priority on mapViewTopConstraint to 1000 thinking that that might help but unfortunately, it didn't make a difference.  Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you try changing `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {` to `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {` for both uses of this code and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @DavidChopin - thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, the behavior is the same using .curveLinear.

Comment: @bmt22033 - the problem is that the actual Map Image is a subview of `MGLMapView` and it is "snapping" to the new height. If you change your animation duration to, say, 3.0 (three seconds), it will be quite obvious. I tried a couple things, but no luck. This may be a question for MapBox tech support.

Comment: @DonMag - per your suggestion, I changed the animation duration to 3s and you're right...the "snapping" is much more apparent now.  I'm going to follow up with Mapbox tech support and see what they have to say.  Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question!